# validate if the newData is an array with firebase database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there a way to validate if the newData is an array in firebase rules?
something like :

```
"node" : { ".validate" : "newData.isArray()" }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no rule to detect whether the data is an array.

Firebase doesn't natively store array. It instead stores the data as a regular JSON object, with numbers as the keys. So

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Is stored as:

```
"0": "one"
"1": "two"
"2": "three"
```

You could check whether the data has a child `0`:

```
".validate" : "newData.child("0").exists()"
```

But this is once again one of the many reasons why experienced Firebasers generally recommends against using arrays. See [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) for some more reasons.